# Submit a job to an asyncio event loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I would like to submit jobs from a thread to an `asyncio` event loop (just like [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) but the other way around).

Here's what the `asyncio` documentation says about [concurrency and multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading):

> To schedule a callback from a different thread, the BaseEventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe() method should be used. 
>   Example to schedule a coroutine from a different thread:
>   `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(asyncio.async, coro_func())`

That works fine but the result of the coroutine is lost.

Instead, it is possible to use a function that adds a done callback to the future returned by `async` (or `ensure_future`) so that the thread can access the result through a [concurrent.futures.Future](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future).

Is there a particular reason why such a feature is not implemented in the standard library? Or did I miss a simpler way to achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My request made its way and a [run_coroutine_threadsafe](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) function has been implemented [here](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/asyncio/tasks.py#L739).

Example:

```
def target(loop, timeout=None):
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(add(1, b=2), loop)
    return future.result(timeout)

async def add(a, b):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return a + b

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = loop.run_in_executor(None, target, loop)
assert loop.run_until_complete(future) == 3
```

---

I originally posted a sub-class of [concurrent.futures.Executor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) that can still be implemented as:

```
class LoopExecutor(concurrent.futures.Executor):
    """An Executor subclass that uses an event loop 
    to execute calls asynchronously."""

    def __init__(self, loop=None):
        """Initialize the executor with a given loop."""
        self.loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        """Schedule the callable, fn, to be executed as fn(*args **kwargs).
        Return a Future object representing the execution of the callable."""
        coro = asyncio.coroutine(fn)(*args, **kwargs)
        return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, self.loop)
```

Comment: do you want to put this in the question so it doesnt seem like an answer

Comment: Well it is kind of [a partial answer to my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), since there might be a better way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: if you see it in that way, ok :)